# How should I incrementally update parquet files?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

So I am having a daily job that will parse CSV into Parquet. Whats the best practice to:

- Incrementally read only new data. Is the only way ensure the input data has some kind of timestamp
- Incrementally output only new data. Currently as a workaround, I will use the write mode "overwrite". But I don't think this will be efficient?

Comment: How often is the CSV generated ? Does the CSV have a fixed schema ? Would the new data be a new file or is it merged in the current file ? Does the CSV data has some kind of date column ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is very simple in theory although the devil is in details

- Incrementally read only new data: Every time your job runs it should remove the data it has processed, or is about to process, from the input directory.  Create a "consumed" directory and move the data there in case you need to playback the data.
- Incrementally output only new data: Using the write mode "Overwrite" is inefficient since you either lose the output of the previous runs or have to process old and new data together.  You could use the "Append" mode to save the data frame to an already existing output directory(ies)

It is very important to note that spark's Append mode could have performance impacts; spark needs to ensure the new output files have unique names.  The more files you have in the destination, the longer it takes for spark to identify the new file names.

Hope this helps.